# Validation for an additional checkbox field in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, checkbox, woocommerce

I have added in checkout page a acceptance field below the terms and conditions field. The new field is about the age validation.

In frontend, I can see my checkbox but customer should not be able to order if checking this checkbox in not checked.
This is the generated html code:

```
<?php if ( wc_terms_and_conditions_checkbox_enabled() ) : ?>
            <p class="form-row validate-required">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="terms" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ), true ); // WPCS: input var ok, csrf ok. ?> id="terms" />
                    <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text"><?php wc_terms_and_conditions_checkbox_text(); ?></span>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1" />
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
                        <p class="form-row validate-required">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" required name="validationage"  id="validationage" />
                    <span class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text"><?php _e( 'Je certifie avoir + de 18 ans', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
            </p>
```

How to enable the validation for this checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will handle your custom checkbox field validation on checkout page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkbox_checkout_validation');
function custom_checkbox_checkout_validation() {
    $field_id = 'validationage';

    if( ! isset( $_POST[$field_id] ) || empty( $_POST[$field_id] ) )
        wc_add_notice( __("validation text.","woocommerce"), "error" );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Great code, but how only trigger it when the user is not logged in. I have got custom checkbox for non-logged users. If user is logged in checkbox disappear, but validation still reporting an error.

Comment: @pat Simply replace the if statement code line with the following `if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( ! isset( $_POST[$field_id] ) || empty( $_POST[$field_id] ) ) )`

Answer (score -1):

It would be much better if you use **woocommerce_after_checkout_validation** hooks, this will let you to be sync with other WooCommerce validation error

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', function( $data, &$errors ) {
    $field_id = 'validationage';
    if( ! isset( $data[$field_id] ) || empty( $data[$field_id] ) ) {
       $errors->add( 'terms', __( 'validation text.', 'theme-slug' ) );
    }
},10, 2  );
```

Note: You may need to use **woocommerce_checkout_fields** filter hook to add custom checkout field.

Thanks